# EJB Persistent Timer not firing on 2nd server when the 1st server shutsdown

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, websphere-liberty

The timer is currently only firing on one server which is what I wanted, but when I shutdown that server down it doesn't start firing on the other server.

- I have 2 liberty 16.x servers both using the same datasource which are connecting to the same network version of a derby db.

**server.xml:**

```
<dataSource id="DefaultDataSource" jndiName="jdbc/DefaultDataSource" connectionSharing="MatchOriginalRequest" commitOrRollbackOnCleanup="rollback">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
    <properties.derby.client databaseName="/opt/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin/databases/TEST_DB" createDatabase="false" serverName="localhost" portNumber="1088"/>
    <containerAuthData user="user1"  password="{xor}XXXX" />
</dataSource>
<library id="DerbyLib">
    <fileset dir="/opt/db-derby-10.13.1.1-bin/lib"/>
</library>
```

- Each server has the same EAR deployed to it with an EJB timer

**EJB:**

```
@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*", persistent=true)  
public void timerExpired()
{
    log.debug("%s collecting status...", System.getProperties().get("wlp.server.name"));
}
```

When they each were using their own embedded version of derby then the timers fired on each server every second. I then switched it to a network version of derby where both servers used the same datasource, and now only one fires which is what I wanted, but I was expecting it to continue firing when the first server was shutdown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server Liberty currently lacks the clustering/failover capability for EJB timers that would allow timers to run on different servers, which you are looking for here.  WebSphere Application Server traditional has this capability, but not Liberty.

You should open a Request For Enhancement with IBM [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/help/submit-rfe/) to represent the requirement to add it to Liberty, and then link to the RFE here so that anyone else who reads this can decide if they want to vote for it to help demonstrate demand for this capability.